# Privoxy css redirection for a specific site doesn't work

Tags: privoxy

When I look at the site exemple.com I would like that server's exemple.css of to be blocked and instead have privoxy use the file perso.css on my server (localhost).

in the default.action file :

`+redirect{http://localhost/perso.css} }
exemple.com/stylesheet\exemple.css`

Yet privoxy continues to load the CSS from the remote server.

Comment: Is the backslash in your path intentional?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I've tried this and technically the construction shown is supposed to work.

However there are several possible problems with this construction:
1) Like Burhan Ali says in the comments why the backslash?
2) The redirect command is wrong because the first character is missing. It is supposed to be:
`{+redirect{http://localhost/perso.css} }`
3) If the stylesheet is not called exactly as shown, then it is not working.
 Since a lot of sites use relative references instead of absolute references it is likely this won't work.
4 If the connection is over https it will not work because Privoxy can't handle this.

These are a few potential issues. There might be others too.